# jquery show a select box text other then what is selected

Tags: jquery, select

I have a hierarchal set of select options with start of string spaces providing indents in my select box options. I would like to show the selected options with the spaces when selecting in the selector, but after choosing a selection I would like the spaces to disappear for the selected option, only to re-appear when selecting again. I can accomplish the first half of this as follows:

```
$('#mySelect').change(function() {
 $("option:selected", this).text($("option:selected",this).text().trim());
});
```

Here is what the simplified html looks like

```
<select id="mySelect">
 <option>root</option>
 <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;nested_one</option>
 <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;nested_two</option>
 <option>another root</option>
 <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;nested_other</option>
</select>
```

What I'm not sure is how to go about setting it back to the original amount of leading spaces. I could stash this qty of spaces in a variable (along with option val/id) and in the on change find and replace it, but even this isn't quite ideal as I would like to trigger the indented value to appear when you open the select options, prior to clicking one. .click seems to fire on open and close which would work, UNLESS your navigating via keyboard only in which case it doesn't trigger at all. Is there a reliable event for when a select is opened to view options?

Maybe I'm going about this wrong, any clever ideas?

Comment: Have you got an image? design? or html? just to illustrate better your idea

Comment: Sure thing, I added the select box html, or a simplified version of it to demonstrate. Basically I want whats visible after selecting to be the option text without the spaces (&nbsp;). The trim works for this, but I would like to instantly add them back when the select box is opened (but not wait for it to be changed/clicked again).

Comment: what if you make it like if that certain option was selected, you add class to that option and just call that class in your css to have spaces on it, ?

Comment: Interesting idea, I could perhaps have a span with a class on it surrounding the &nbsp; and make it display: none if selected, that's a cool idea, still doesn't completely handle the when you open the selector removing the class as I'm not aware of a consistent event for that, but its a cool approach. ++

Comment: you could make it in jquery when that option is selected, 1st you remove all the options class then add class to that certain option. i could try to make an example if you want

Comment: No need for example, I get the idea, only issue though is .click does not happen when using the keyboard, and I would prefer to perform the swap before actually selecting the option (ie .change), IE when you open the select box. Another wild idea I had was an absolute div with no-pointer events with a higher z value that I just update the text on..... not sure how well that will line up, but it might work too.

Comment: cool, that's better i guess (~~,)b

Comment: All good ideas!, the higher z-div does seem to be working well actually, I'll post some details on it if I get it figured out. And I'm reversing my last comment, if you feel like writing up some code go for it, that's what stack overflow is all about, what was I thinking : ' /

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this  appears to work well in firefox and chrome on Ubuntu, although I'm skeptical it will work well on all browsers, as I'm skeptical the overlapping inputs will always line up/appear correct, so far so good though:

HTML

```
<select id="mySelect" style="position: absolute; width: 300px;">
 <option>root</option>
 <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;nested_one</option>
 <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;nested_two</option>
 <option>another root</option>
 <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;nested_other</option>
</select>

<select id="mySelectOverlay" style="position: absolute; width: 300px; z-index: 100; pointer-events: none;">
  <option>root</option>
</select>
```

JQuery

```
$('#mySelect').change(function() {
 var trimmed = $("option:selected", this).text().trim();
 $("option:selected", $('#mySelectOverlay')).text(trimmed);
});
```

This might break with certain browsers and/or not be the best solution, but it appears to do the job.